# Ghostdoc creates a help folder, but no .chm file

Tags: ghostdoc

I have installed Ghostdoc enterprise and the visual studio 2017 extention. I have installed htmlhelp. Every time I build help documentation, either through cmd or through visual studio itself, a help folder is created, but that folder is empty, while there should be a .chm file. There seem to be no errors, only "No APIs found to document"

Could anyone help me out with this or point me in a direction where I can get help

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you select appropriate "Scope to include" in the help configuration dialog. It only includes the public types by default in which case if there are no public classes in the project you will get the "No APIs found to document" warning. I hope this helps.